# Does Vowpal Wabbit's Python interface support a single call for model training/testing?

Tags: python, vowpalwabbit

I've been trying to develop a CB model using Vowpal Wabbit. Following all the online tutorials I could find, I started by training and testing in Python by looping over records:

```
vw = pyvw.vw("--cb_explore_adf")

for i in range(df.shape[0]):

        # format example into vw-friendly format
        new_line = to_vw_format_train(df.iloc[i])

        #vw learn from each line
        vw_line = vw.parse(new_line, pyvw.vw.lContextualBandit)
        vw.learn(vw_line)

# save model for future use
vw.save('vw.model')
```

However, I noticed that calling VW from the command line gives you a more succinct way of training/testing. For example, if I had all records in a VW-friendly format (vw_training_set.txt) I could run:

```
vw -d vw_training_set.txt --cb_explore_adf -p train_predictions.txt -f vw.model
```

My questions are:

1. Assuming all parameters are equal, is there any difference in these two approaches?
2. If not, is there a way to perform training in Python without explicitly looping over each example?

Edit: I have tried to use pyvw to run the following:

```
from vowpalwabbit import pyvw
import os

pywd = "directory"
os.chdir(pywd)

# testing built in functionality
test_records = """shared |User var:5
Action 1:-1:0.5 | treatment=1
| treatment=2
    
shared |User var:3
| treatment=1
Action 2:-2:0.5 | treatment=2
"""
    
vw_train_records = open(r"test_file.txt","w+")
vw_train_records.write(test_records)
vw_train_records.close()
    
vw = pyvw.vw("-d test_file.txt --cb_explore_adf -p train_predictions.txt")
vw.save('vw.model')
vw.finish()
```

The train_predictions file is created, but it is not populated. The vw.model file is also created, but it doesn't seem like its learned anything.

Edit 2: Updated example w/ vw.finish()

Edit 3: Updated example to include correct spacing

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Assuming all parameters are equal, is there any difference in these two approaches?

Yes I believe they should be equivalent, except for the `-p train_predictions.txt`. That isn't present in the Python snippet.

> 2. not, is there a way to perform training in Python without explicitly looping over each example?

Not exactly, but it's a great suggestion and something we should look at adding.

You can kind of do this by leveraging the fact that currently (this may change in further versions) `pyvw` initializes the vw instance with the options passed to the constructor and it has logic to tell if a data file is passed to process it.

So this should work:

```py
vw = pyvw.vw("-d vw_training_set.txt --cb_explore_adf -p train_predictions.txt")
vw.save('vw.model')
```

Comment: Thank you -- I've updated the main post to show my attempt at using pyvw, though I'm not able to produce any predictions

Comment: The problem may be that the vw object is not 'finished'. Can you try calling `vw.finish()` after `vw.save(...)`. I would have thought it would have happened automatically but maybe not?

Comment: Added vw.finish() (see main post), but doesn't seem to be making a difference. Is there anything wrong with the way the mock data is setup?

Comment: Ah I see, the labels used for actions are incorrect. Please take a look at this tutorial to understand how to structure them: https://vowpalwabbit.org/tutorials/contextual_bandits.html 

Quick answer though `Action 1:-1:0.5|` should be `1:-1:0.5 |` (take note of the whitespace before `|`)

Comment: Thanks -- I took a look and added the whitespace before | e.g. `1:-1:0.5 |` and after, e.g. `| treatment = 1`. Still not able to produce predictions. Are you able to run this on your machine?